# After login, Spring Security redirects to login page again

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 4.1.1, and I'm having an issue: I try to access an URL, the application redirects to login page. So far so good.

But, after a successful login, the application redirects me to the login page again and it doesn't create any session so that even trying to access the URL directly (typing it at URL bar), the application redirects to the login page.

There are some URL I have to ask for login to access them. The others, I can access with no authentication. These URL that I don't need authentication work perfectly (i.e. no login is asked and the URL is accessed), but those URL that need authentication asks for login, but after typing user name and the password, it's redirected to login page again and I can't access the URL directly.

My configure() method is this:

```
// Those URL pattern I need authentication to access them.
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/gerenciar/**", "/admin/adicionar/**", "/admin/index.html", "/admin/").
            authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login.html").permitAll();
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to post any other code to clarify my question or help others to answer me. If so, please tell me so I can update my question.

EDIT 1

A question: I want to ask for authentication for those URL in the antMatchers() method parameters: do I need to write "/admin/index.html" and "/admin/"? Is it the same for Spring Security?

EDIT 2

URL I want to let everybody access: "/" and "/admin/resources/**". Inside /admin/resources, I have css and js, and that's why I want everybody access them. There's no need of authentication for those URL.

I need people to authenticate for URL: "/admin/gerenciar/**", "/admin/adicionar/**" and "/admin/" (implicitly saying "/admin/index.html", of course).

My question now is: how can I do a code for that (inside configure() method)?

Comment: Any errors in the logs? Also it would help if you can post the spring logs (spring log level = debug)

Comment: I didn't know about that. I'll search for it, and I'll post it here after turning it on.

Comment: I would suggest to turn debug logs on in spring and then check

Comment: Do you guys mean creating log4j.properties and set rootLogger to debug?

Comment: I created log4j.properties, set config log4jConfigLocation param in web.xml, it started to log more stuff than usual (as expected), BUT no ERROR logged after typing user/pass.

Comment: Is antMatchers "/admin/" and "/admin/index.html" preventing access to /admin/adicionar/** or "/admin/gerenciar/**"? Try /admin/**. Also try .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index.html")

Comment: I thought that, after sending my user/pass I could access those URL. I tried "/admin/**" and no success. I tried .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index.html") and no success either.

Comment: The other thing i noticed is that I think that antMatchers should be followed by permitAll().anyRequest()

Comment: @farrellmr May you see my EDIT 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is -

Anyone can access /, admin/login.html and /admin/resources/**,
But not the other admin urls?

I think the method should be -

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/admin/login.html", "/admin/resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/admin/gerenciar/**", "/admin/adicionar/**").
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin/login.html")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. It doesn't even create a session. If I type wrong or correct user/pass, then no message comes to me. I don't get any "Wrong combination of user/pass" or any message saying to me that I typed it wrong.

Comment: I done a similar example on my github accoutn at - https://github.com/farrelmr/parkrunpbreboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/glenware/springboot/WebSecurityConfig.java

Comment: No success. The problem is: how to ask for password for some URL and don't ask for others? If I write anyRequest().authenticated(), I'll ask for authentication for every URL, and that's not what I want.

Comment: If you look at the two matchers - the first allows access to urls without permission, the second is specific directories. As a test remove /admin/** from the second and try accessing the nonsecure urls or files. Also up the logging. Are there files under /admin/ or just the child dirs

Comment: Id also consider moving the static assets from the admin section if they are used elsewhere on the site as it risks a simple error exposing your admin section

Comment: I haven't seen your edit. I think everything is fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Once the login has been successful, Spring security redirects to "/" and then, I checks if the user is authenticated and in this case, redirects it to my dashboard page.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken))
            return "dashboard";

        // if it is not authenticated, then go to the index...
        // other things ...
        return "index";
    }
```